# Why I cant query to Firebase eventhough the query is correct?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have posted yesterday about the same problem I am having but I just can't get it to work I really need help on this more than ever!

I will post the entire function below:

```
const db = firebase.firestore; //initializing database
//setting state here, removed for brevity
_checkForUniqueDevice() {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    this.state.currentUser = currentUser;

    const document = db().collection('RriNshpiUsers').doc('EzGNfNl63LQvjdauFWosG08Ishj2');
    const ref = document.collection('private').doc('ApbckRkRITeh0WQIiQiz');
    const publicDoc = document.collection('public').doc('aRzHZ8zro7XFpkJMg1TH');

    const updateFunction = async transaction => {
        const [active] = await Promise.all([
            transaction.get(ref),
        ]);
        const { location } = this.state;
        let timestamp = moment(location.timestamp).format("MM-DD-YYYY h:mm:ss")

        const user_active = active.data().act;
        const device_id = active.data().devID;

        if (user_active === 0 && device_id === '') {
            transaction.update(ref, {
                devID: this.state.deviceId,
                act: 1,
                time: timestamp,
                lat: location.latitude,
                course: location.course,
                speed: location.speed,
                alt: location.altitude,
                long: location.longitude,
                acc: location.accuracy,
                altAcc: location.altitudeAccuracy,
                courseAcc: location.courseAccuracy,
                speedAcc: location.speedAccuracy
            });
                transaction.update(publicDoc, {
                addCoord: location
            });
        }
    };
     db().runTransaction(updateFunction)
        .then(result => {
          //never returns something
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //never catches any errors
        });
}
```

I am using this function which I have used somewhere else where it worked perfectly fine,  but I can't understand why is it failing silently here?

When I call this function, it executes the first line where it's building the query then it goes to `db().runTransaction(updateFunction)` this line and tries to execute but doesn't catch any errors nor it returns anything in the callback - I have put breakpoints in `.catch` and `.then` callback but never stops there.

If there is an error, isn't it suppose to catch it? Or if it succeeds isn't it supposed to return something in the callback?

Any idea what's going on here?

**EDIT: screenshots**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in my code was setting state inside the transaction operation and this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) clearly states that should not be done.